# Fibonacci Generating Function of a Complex Variable

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

So I'm doing work on the Fibonacci Numbers, and I came across this problem for the generating function
[image]

for the recursive fibonacci numbers. 
[image: This is the problem]

I have two questions: 
1. Why is it useful to use a complex variable $z^n$ as apposed to a real variable $x^n$? 
2. What does it mean by derive an identity for $f_n$? 
Note that 
$f_0 = 0$, 
$f_1 = 1$, 
$f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: If you are going to refer to Theorem 9.9, don't you think it might be a good idea to state which book that comes from? - Theorem 9.9 in my book has nothing to do with complex variables and Fibonacci numbers ...

Comment: I apoligize. It can be found here: http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/complex.pdf

Comment: @Old John, I take your point, but the Residue Theorem in your book is quite likely to be the same as the Residue Theorem in OP's book.

Comment: Anthony, how would you propose to integrate a function of a real variable around a circle in the complex plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's much easier to understand power series in the context of complex analysis than real analysis. (The sum of a power series is an analytic function, and those are exactly the ones you study in complex analysis. Also, the radius of convergence is directly related to the singularities of this analytic function.)
2. You want to find a *formula* for $f_n$. Have you tried following the hint? (Recall Cauchy's integral formula to relate the integral to the value of $f_n$.)

Comment: In what manner is the radius of convergence related to the singularities? I personally know that it is, but in what way? Also, about number two, I still don't understand what it's asking because obviously the formula for fn is fn= fn-1 + fn-2.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter The power series of $f(z)$ centered at $z=a$ converges on the largest disc $\{ |z-a| = R \}$ on which $f$ is analytic. I.e. (somewhat sloppily) the radius of convergence is the distance to the closest singularity.

Comment: Anthony, what's wanted is a formula for $f_n$ that depends only on $n$, and not on previous values of $f$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, that would make much more sense. How would the provided hint help do this though?

Comment: Anthony, have you tried doing the integration? Or maybe what you are missing is the connection between $F(z)$ and the function you are asked to integrate --- you should think about that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know that the (1)(1-z-z^2) is the g(x) for fn, but I don't know why they are adding the z^n+1 nor why it must be around a circle of radius R.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter. Have you even read the hint I gave? **Recall Cauchy's integral formula**

Comment: Anthony, the way to see why the $z^{n+1}$ and why the circle is to do the integration and see what happens. If you still have questions after you've done the integration, report back on the results you obtained, and ask your questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Would these methods simply let me find Binet's formula? Or would this find a different formula for fn?

Comment: Anthony, why do you keep asking what *would* happen instead of doing the work and seeing what *does* happen?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I personally do not know how to evaluate this integral, and before I take the time to do so, I want to know if I will arrive at Binet's formula, or something different.

Comment: Anthony, you could have saved everyone a lot of grief if you had just mentioned at the start that you don't know how to evaluate the integral. Anyway, I think your two questions have been answered: we use a complex variable because we're in the complex plane, and you now know what's meant by an identity for $n$. So, this question is done. If you have another, then by all means post another question (but, please, next time, put all your cards on the table from the get-go).