# Fibonacci Numbers - Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers, residue-calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex Analysis - Integral over a circle of radius R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281109/complex-analysis-integral-over-a-circle-of-radius-r)

Hey guys~  Does anyone know where to find the solutions to this problem set on page 106 involving the fibonacci numbers?:
http://www.math.binghamton.edu/sabalka/teaching/09Spring375/Chapter10.pdf
This is non-homework related, and simply for fun. If anyone would be willing to take the time and post the solutions, it would be much appreciated. Or if anyone knows where to find the full solutions, please let me know.  Thank you~ (P.S. Sorry about not being able to post an image of the problem set. As a new user, I'm not allowed to post images)