# Proof That the Ratio of Sucessive N-nacci Numbers Tends to 2.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, complex-analysis, fibonacci-numbers

For the paper that I'm working on involving N-nacci Recursion Formulas I need to prove that $$ \lim_ {n \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty} \left | \frac{f^{(n)}_{a+1}}{f^{(n)}_a} \right | = 2$$
To start we know that

$$ \lim_ {n \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty} \left | \frac{f^{(n)}_{a+1}}{f^{(n)}_{a}} \right | = \lim_ {n \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty} \left | \frac{f^{(n)}_{a}+f^{(n)}_{a-1}+f^{(n)}_{a-2} + \cdots +f^{(n)}_{a-(n-1)}}{f^{(n)}_{a-1}+f^{(n)}_{a-2}+f^{(n)}_{a-3} + \cdots + f^{(n)}_{a-n}} \right | =\lim_ {n \to \infty} \lim_{a \to \infty} \left | \frac{f^{(n)}_{a-(n-1)}}{f^{(n)}_{a-n}} \right |$$
$$= \lim_ {n \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty} \left | \frac{f^{(n)}_{a+1}}{f^{(n)}_{a}} \right | $$
Where would I go from here?
Link to my work for my paper thus far:
[N-nacci Identities: The Final Question (Generalizing Time!)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283266/n-nacci-identities-the-final-question-generalizing-time)

Comment: So, this is the question after the final question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I felt that it was just too clustered within the last question to include this one. I felt it would be better to ask it seperately. This question relates fully to the other one. Also, "The Final Question" refers to number 5 in the problem set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember working on this at least 30 years ago - maybe more. I'll try to activate my WayBack machine.

To find (actually, estimate) the root of 
$f(x) = x^n-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-\cdots-x^2-x-1=0$:

$x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x^2+x+1 =
(x^n-1)/(x-1)$,
so $f(x) = x^n - (x^n-1)/(x-1)
= (x^{n+1}-x^n - x^n + 1)/(x-1)
= (x^{n+1}-2x^n+ 1)/(x-1)
$.
We thus want to find out
where the root of $g(x) = x^{n+1}-2x^n+ 1=0$ is.

$g'(x) = (n+1)x^n - 2n x^{n-1}
= x^{n-1}((n+1)x-2n)
$
so $g'(x) > 0$ for $x > 2n/(n+1) = 2-2/(n+1)$.

$g(2) > 0$
and
$g(x) = x^n (x-2)+1$
so

$\begin{align}
g(2-2/(n+1)) &= (2-2/(n+1))^n(-2/(n+1))+1 \\
&= -2^n(1-1/(n+1))^n (2/(n+1))+1\\
&= -2^{n+1}(n/(n+1))^n/(n+1) + 1 \\
&< -2^{n+1}/(e(n+1)) + 1 \\
&< 0 
\end{align}
$.

Thus $g$ (and $f$) have a root between
$2$ and $2-2/(n+1)$,
so the root approaches 2 for large $n$.

Comment: So would this be a suitable proof to use in my paper? If I want to use the original post as a lemma I mean

Comment: The first question, Anthony, is: do you understand it? If not, then it certainly isn't a suitable proof to use.

Answer (score 2):

If $a_n$ satisfies any homogeneous constant coefficient linear recurrence, and if the characteristic polynomial for the recurrence has a unique root $\alpha$ of greatest modulus, then (unless the initial conditions are weird) $a_{n+1}/a_n\to\alpha$ as $n\to\infty$.

The root of $x^n-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-\cdots-x^2-x-1=0$ of greatest modulus approaches $2$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Where does the $x^n-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-\cdots-x^2-x-1=0$ polynomial come from?

Comment: @Anthony: It’s the [characteristic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) of the recurrence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If I wanted to use this as a Lemma in a paper, how would I begin it's proof?

Comment: What is the purpose of this paper? This material is ancient history, for any purpose I can think of you wouldn't give a proof, you'd give a reference to a textbook where it's covered. Are you writing a textbook?

Comment: @GerryMyerson 
The paper is not about this above proof. It's just a lemma for a paper.

Comment: My remark still applies --- I wouldn't prove this lemma in a paper, I'd give a reference. BUt again, that depends on the nature/purpose of the paper.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I have emailed you regarding the purpose of this paper. Please let me know if you received that email

Comment: @GerryMyerson Note that this will be my *first* mathematics paper.

Comment: Anthony, I am not interested in entering into email correspondence with you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The condescending attitude is rather off-putting. But it's alright, I guess some people are nicer than others.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: Gerry does not sound condescending. He is simply letting you know that he won't be corresponding with you via email.