# Find the roots of $\lambda^8 -2\lambda^7+1=0$ (characteristic polynomial)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, polynomials, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Can't find the roots of a seemingly simple characteristic polynomial

$\lambda^8 -2\lambda^7+1=0$

I failed factoring.

Is it possible to find the roots? Can you show me how?

Comment: $\lambda=1$ is a root by inspection

Comment: $\lambda=1$ is an obvious root, so there are seven others of which at least one is real, presumably close to but not equal to $2$

Comment: There is (almost) no such thing as a simple octic polynomial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You have answered this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283958/proof-that-the-ratio-of-sucessive-n-nacci-numbers-tends-to-2?noredirect=1), in $2013$. There is exactly one real root, besides $x=1$, between
$2$ and $2-2/(n+1)$, for $n=7$.

Answer (score 1):

The factorisation into irreducible factors in $\Bbb Q[x]$ is given by $$x^8-2x^7+1=(x-1)(x^7-x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1).$$ The real roots are $x=1$ and $x=1.99196419661$. For details see this post:

[Irreducibility of an infinite sequence of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334051/irreducibility-of-an-infinite-sequence-of-polynomials?noredirect=1)

Indeed, $f(x) = x^n-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-\cdots-x^2-x-1=0$ has exactly one real root, which is between $2$ and $2-\frac{2}{n+1}$,
so the root approaches $2$ for large $n$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The polynomial relates to flipping a coin and 7 heads in a row. ($y_n=2y_{n-1} - y_{n-8}$) So it's not a typo.

Comment: Because $y_n$ means an integer coefficient of some polynomial, I thought the roots of $x^8-2x^7+1 = 0$ must be in Q in the first place. How can I get the complex roots?

Comment: My goal is to set up $y_n = a_1\lambda_1^n + ... +a_8\lambda_8^n$. If I get the other complex roots, is it possible with converting complex to trigonometric(Wikipedia says)?

Comment: There is a lot known about the roots of $x^n-x^{n-1}-\cdots -x-1$, see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332410/roots-of-xn-xn-1-cdots-x-1), but to compute them you will need a numerical method, I suppose.

Comment: And for coins with $7$ in a row see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/what-is-the-probability-of-a-coin-landing-tails-7-times-in-a-row-in-a-series-of): "The asymptotic growth of $a_n$ is controlled by the largest positive root of the characteristic polynomial $x^7 = x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$, which is a little less than $2$." This answer should be helpful. You don't need the complex roots. You should add this context about coins in your post!

Comment: Thank you very much! The post you mentioned is like a perfect answer.