# Fibonacci( Binet's Formula Derivation)-Revised with work shown

Tags: complex-analysis, fibonacci-numbers, residue-calculus

Okay so here is the revised question with my current work.

Links to previous post(s)(Just for Gerry): [Fibonacci Numbers - Complex Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282269/fibonacci-numbers-complex-analysis)

Here's my attempt on the problem set thus far: (Note that $\bullet$ represents a completed problem (in my opinion) while $\circ$ represents a semi-completed problem.)
~Problem set can be found on page 106: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/sabalka/teaching/09Spring375/Chapter10.pdf

(2) To derive a generating function for $f_n$, note that the fibonacci series is defined by the sequence of numbers $(0,1,f_1+f_0,f_2+f_1,...f_n+f_n-1)$.
If we break this up into three separate generating functions and sum them to obtain the generating function $F(z)$ it will look something like:
$$(0,1,0,0,0...) \rightarrow\,z)$$
$$+(0,f_0,f_1,f_2,...)\to\,zF(z)$$ for a $F(z) = f_0+f_1z+f_2z^2+...+f_nz^n$ 
$$+ (0,0,,f_0,f_1,f_2,...)\to z^2F(z)$$ for the same $F(z)$
This all equals $$(0,1+f_0,f_1+f_0,f_2+f_1,f_3+f_2,...)\to z+zF(z)+z^2F(z)$$
Therefore $F(z)=z+zF(z)+z^2F(z)$, solving for $F(z)$ we obtain
$$F(z) = \frac {z}{1-z-z^2} \bullet$$
P.S. I don't understand why it says $\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$ instead of  $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$ in the original problem set. Is it because they're excluding the $f_0$ and $f_1$ terms?

~

I felt that it would make more sense to do (2) before (1) so here's (1)
*First note that by the quadratic formula, the two roots of the denominator are $\varphi,\bar \varphi$ where $\varphi= \frac {1+\sqrt5}{2}$.
So $F(z)$ has a positive radius of convergence by the ratio test which gives
$r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_n+1}{f_n}= \bar \varphi \bullet$

~

(3) Now to show that $Res (\frac{1}{z^n+1(1-z-z^2)})$ at $z=0$ = $f_n$
I know that you must use the formula:
$Res(f,c) = \frac{1}{n-1!}\lim_{z\to c}\frac{d^n-1}{dz^n-1} ((z-c)^nF(z)$ for a pole of order n. I need a little help here. I'm also confused as to where they get the $z^n+1$ from. Why does it appear there?      $\circ$

**Edit**

I realized that since
$$1=Res_{z=0}z^{-1}$$ then  z^n+1 would be the extracting term:
$$f_n=Res_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \sum_{n>1}{f_nz^n}$$
Is this correct?

**Edit** According to Brian M. Scott, the proper work for this problem (3) is
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)}\right)&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(z^{n+1}\frac1{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)}\right)\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\big(F(z)\big)\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\sum_{k\ge 0}f_kz^k\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k\ge 0}f_k\frac{d^n}{dz^n}z^k\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k\ge n}f_k \Big( \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (k-i) \Big)z^{k-n}\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\left(f_nn!+\sum_{k>n}f_k \Big( \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (k-i) \Big) z^{k-n}\right)\\
&=f_n+\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}z\sum_{k\ge n+1}f_k \Big( \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (k-i) \Big) z^{k-(n+1)}\\
&=f_n\; \bullet
\end{align*}$$
I follow this work until the third to last step where I don't understand how he obtained the $f_nn!$ term. Any Explanations?

(4) 
Using the residue theorem $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{\rho} \text{Res}(f(z)),z=\rho)$$
Now quite obviously applying this:
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)} = 2 \pi i [f_n + R\varphi + R_{\bar \varphi}]$$
Okay, so obviously we must parametrize over a circle of radius R. This parametrization is $\gamma(t) = Re^{it}$ because a circle is just a simple curve.
Performing a change of variables, we obtain  $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{i R e^{it} dt}{R^{n+1}e^{it(n+1)}(1-(Re^{it})-(Re^{it})^2)}$$
The only reason that I personally thought of why this integral $\to 0$ is because the one can trivially see that the denominator would be $>>$ than the numerator because you have $\infty$ raised to a power.
  I'm also confused as to why it's even necessary to show that this integral disappears as the Radius of the circle approaches $\infty$. Could someone care to explain?

Finally, for the exact calculations of $(R\varphi, R_{\bar \varphi})$
First note that $(1-z-z^2)=(\varphi + z)(\bar \varphi-z)
$$R_\varphi = \text{Res}(\frac{1}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)},z=\varphi) = \lim_{z \to \varphi}\frac{z-\varphi}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)} = \lim_{z \to -\varphi}\frac{z-\varphi}{z^{n+1}(\varphi + z)(\bar \varphi-z)} =\frac{1}{\varphi^{n+1}(1-\bar \varphi)}$$  
  Alternatively,  
$$R_\bar \varphi = \text{Res}(\frac{1}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)},z=\bar \varphi) = \lim_{z \to \bar \varphi}\frac{z-\bar \varphi}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)} = \lim_{z \to \bar \varphi}\frac{z-\bar \varphi}{z^{n+1}(\varphi + z)(\bar \varphi-z)} =\frac{1}{\bar \varphi^{n+1}(1- \varphi)} \circ$

(5) Requires the completion of (4)

This is all of my current work that I have thus far. I honestly do not know where to go from my last step in (4). I still need to arrive at a final identity for $f_n$. So I need to know how to continue this work. Any hints, etc?
Thanks!~

**Edit**

I now understand that $$f_n=Res (F(z)) at z=0= \Big(Res(F(z) at z=0 + Res(F(z) at z= \varphi + Res(F(z) at z=\bar \varphi\Big) - \Big(Res(F(z) at z= \varphi + Res(F(z) at z=\bar \varphi\Big) = {2\pi i}\int F(z)dz - - \Big(Res(F(z) at z= \varphi + Res(F(z) at z=\bar \varphi\Big) = - \Big(Res(F(z) at z= \varphi + Res(F(z) at z=\bar \varphi\Big) $$ because the integral $$2\pi i\int F(z)dz \to 0$$ as $R \to \infty$

Is this correct?

Comment: I think I got it in my notebook.

Comment: @GitGud The solution set?

Comment: It's a bit different, sorry. I'm sure this is a classic, though. Should be easy to find on Google.

Comment: @GitGud haven't been able to find any sort of solution set on Google

Comment: Page 7 on the following link solves it partially: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/class/harvard/213a/course/course.pdf
Page 82: https://www.hack-talk.info/books/An_Introduction_to_Complex_Analysis_and_Geometry.pdf

Comment: @GitGud I'm interested in the solutions in the style in which the solution set asks, because I've seen solutions to this problem, but not in the ways that are asked above in the problem set.

Comment: @GitGud Would you mind posting the solution set? It would be very very appreciated.

Comment: Like I said above, what I got is different It would go something along the lines of the last link I posted. So there's no point.

Comment: @GitGud Well would you mind doing these problems and posting the solutions? I know it's a lot to ask, but I would really be grateful

Comment: It's right there on the last link, you just have to work through it.

Comment: @GitGud But they don't utilize any integrals of any sort.

Comment: @GitGud If you could work out the solutions and post them, I would be thrilled

Comment: Hi Anthony.  I would be happy to help you work through the solution yourself if you could post any work you have so far along with specific questions about where you are stuck.  This would prevent me from telling you things you already know and would allow me to help you at the appropriate level.

Comment: I guess Anthony is going to keep on asking this question in various disguises until someone spoonfeeds the answer. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281109/complex-analysis-integral-over-a-circle-of-radius-r and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280378/fibonacci-generating-function-of-a-complex-variable --- Anthony, it is **extremely unethical to keep posting this problem without linking to your previous questions!**

Comment: @GerryMyerson I apoligize, I didn't realize that I needed to provide links to the previous postings. I'm new to the forum

Comment: Baloney. The record speaks for itself.

Comment: Anthony, I'll be frank.  It's time for you to go and learn the concepts relevant to this question and its solution on your own, say from a textbook about complex analysis.  You have been given more than enough advice on what to look for.

Comment: Are http://math.stackexchange.com/users/58432/anthony-peter and http://math.stackexchange.com/users/58540/anthony-peter the same persons? If so maybe the moderators should be asked to merge the accounts.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter If you really are studying this yourself and not trying to cheat on homework, just post these as questions, including your progress towards a solution, instead of just asking for a solutions manual.  Then we will help you...

Comment: @AlexanderGruber 1. It's not a homework assignment. 2. That's fair I guess. Except I can't do MathJax.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I would have posted my attempts if I had any knowledge of how to properly format it.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter What's keeping your from learning?  It's really not that hard, you mainly just put things in dollars signs

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I just have always thought it would be a long and tedious process. That's why I'm asking for solutions to compare what I have and what the actual answers are. If I was good at proper formatting, I would have no problem with posting my work thus far. Although it looks fairly similar to user58512's. Similar, but not identical.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter It's not involved at all, all you have to do is type what you want between dollars signs.  Use `x^2` to exponentiate, to make fractions use `\frac{ numerator } { denominator }`, `\greeklettername` for a greek letter, etc.  Just google "how do I do (blank) in latex" if you can't figure something out.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber So can I open a new thread with my current work?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter By the way [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is linked in the FAQ, which I recommend you read before continuing

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Yes, if you read the FAQ first and make sure your question meets community standards (i.e. includes your progress, is specific/answerable).

Comment: You **still** refuse to link to all the previous incarnations of this question! You are hopeless!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Acceptable now?

Comment: Hopeless. Hopeless. Hopeless.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 1. I don't really appreciate the negativity. 2. Why?

Comment: The record speaks for itself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why do you have to have such a condescendingly pompous tone? I'm just trying to work on this problem set. I've given my personal attempt at the problem set above. Please, stop being such a rude person.

Comment: If you have one question, ask it once. You can amend the question with your work and even post an answer, should you discover one. Posting several questions about the same problem is not appropriate. Your links "Just for Gerry" are not just for Gerry. They should be there, whether Gerry asked for them or not. If you *are* going to ask several questions regarding the same problem, you should at least link them.

Comment: Anthony, while I think that Gerry is overreacting, I don't think he's ever said anything condescending or pompous. He has asked you extremely directly on two other occasions to do something which is exceedingly important and exceptionally simple, and you failed to do so. After the last discussion you seemed to have learned your lesson, and apparently you did not (hopefully you have learned it now). He is frustrated by this. There's not much more to it than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got $F(z)=\dfrac{z}{1-z-z^2}$ because you used the standard indexing of the Fibonacci numbers that makes $f_0=0$; your coefficient sequence is $\langle 0,1,1,2,\dots\rangle$. The problem set has $f_0=f_1=1$, so its coefficient sequence is $\langle 1,1,2,3,\dots\rangle$. Yours is right-shifted one place, an operation that corresponds to multiplication by $z$, so your generating function is $z$ times that of the problem. The generating function for the sequence as given in the problem is therefore $\dfrac1zF(z)=\dfrac1{1-z-z^2}$.

---

The zeroes of $1-z-z^2$ are $\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2$, or $-\varphi$ and $\dfrac1\varphi$, where as usual $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{f_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{f_nz^n}\right|=|z|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}=\varphi|z|\;,$$

so the radius of convergence is $\dfrac1\varphi=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt5}2$; if this is what you’re calling $\overline\varphi$, your conclusion is correct, but there are some errors along the way to it.

---

You want to show that $$\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)}\right)=f_n\;.$$ $0$ is a pole of order $n+1$ of the function in parentheses, so you have the formula

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)}\right)&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(z^{n+1}\frac1{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)}\right)\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\big(F(z)\big)\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\sum_{k\ge 0}f_kz^k\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k\ge 0}f_k\frac{d^n}{dz^n}z^k\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k\ge n}f_kk(k-1)(k-2)\ldots(k-n+1)z^{k-n}\\
&=\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\left(f_nn!+\sum_{k>n}f_kk(k-1)(k-2)\ldots(k-n+1)z^{k-n}\right)\\
&=f_n+\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}z\sum_{k\ge n+1}f_kk(k-1)\ldots(k-n+1)z^{k-(n+1)}\\
&=f_n\;.
\end{align*}$$

---

I’ll leave the rest to someone whose complex analysis doesn’t have some $35$ years of rust on it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you mind elaborating a little on the $Res(F(z))$ at$z=0$  = $f_n$? To begin, I don't understand where you pulled the $f_nn!$ from in the third to last step.

Comment: Where does the extra $z^{n+1}$ come from in the first step?

Comment: $$\frac1{n!}\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k\ge n}f_k \Big( \prod_{0}^{n+1} (k-n) \Big) z^{k-n}\\$$   Could you write it like this instead?

Comment: @Anthony: (1) $f_nn!$ is the first term of the sum $\sum_{k\ge n}f_kk(k-1)\dots(k-n+1)z^{k-n}$, the term when $k=n$; I just pulled it out of the summation. (2) I want a pole of order $n+1$ at $0$, so I divide $F(z)$, which has no pole at $0$, by $z^{n+1}$. (3) Not quite: $\prod_0^{n+1}(k-n)$ is $(k-n)^{n+2}$. The correct product is $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(k-i))$. That product is a [*falling factorial*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol), for which I prefer the notation $k^{\underline n}$, though $(k)_n$ is also fairly common.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott. (1) Good, that was my first thought. (2) I understand that, but why do you divide and multiply by $z^n+1$? I know that the $z^n+1$ is used to pull out a term $f_n$, but I'm unclear as to why you put it as a product and a divisor. Is it simply to keep $F(z)$ the same? Did you simply reduce it to 1? (3) Ahh, okay that makes sense.

Comment: @Anthony: The $z^{n+1}$ in the denominator is to get a pole of order $n+1$; the one in the numerator corresponds to the $(z-c)^n$ in the [limit formula for higher order poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles), since $c=0$, and we have a pole of order $n+1$, not $n$. The two cancel to leave just $F(z)$ inside the derivative, which is perfect, since the $n$-th derivative then isolates $f_n$.

Comment: Oh, that would make perfect sense now. Just out of curiosity, why is it of such importance to get a pole of order $n+1$?

Comment: @Anthony: Because it has the desired residue $f_n$. No other reason.

Comment: Understood. Are the residues for $ \varphi$ and $\bar \varphi$ correct?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on the Ratio Test? How does $ \varphi|z|= \bar \varphi$?

Comment: @Anthony: $\varphi|z|$ isn’t $1/\varphi$. For convergence you need $\varphi|z|<1$, or $|z|<1/\varphi$.

Comment: @Anthony: For the previous question, you still seem to have the wrong factorization of $1-z-z^2$: the roots are $-\varphi$ and $1/\varphi$, the latter apparently being your $\overline\varphi$. I suggest looking at robjohn’s answer for that part of the problem.

Comment: So the roots would be $(z+ \varphi)(z+ \bar \varphi)$?

Comment: @Anthony: No, the roots are $-\varphi$ and $\overline\varphi$. The quadratic $z^2+z-1$ factors as $(z+\varphi)(z-\overline\varphi)$, and the original $1-z-z^2$ factors as $(z+\varphi)(\overline\varphi-z)$.

Comment: Alright, now how would the residues be evaluated?

Comment: Using the Residue theorem for simple poles I mean.

Comment: @Anthony: robjohn has done it in his answer. (Note, though, that he used your $F(z)$, corresponding to $f_0=0$, where I used the $F(z)$ of the problem set, corresponding to $f_0=1$.)

Comment: could you elaborate on this part? The residue of $\dfrac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}$ at $\omega_\pm$ is $\dfrac1{\omega_\pm^n(\omega_\mp-\omega_\pm)}$; i.e. multiply by $(z-\omega_\pm)$ and evaluate at $\omega_\pm$.

Comment: @Anthony: it’s just [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles).

Comment: Did he use the first formula?

Comment: @Anthony: Yes; in this case the limit is simply the value at $\omega_{\pm}$.

Comment: Is the notation I used in (3) correct now? I'm referring to the edited work from the original post. Also, Why does it change from $k \ge n$ to $k \ge n+1$?

Comment: and why doe the exponent of $z^{k-n}$ change to $z^{k-(n+1)}$?

Comment: @Anthony: (1) Because I pulled the $k=n$ term out of the summation. We talked about that before: that’s where the $f_nn!$ came from. (2) Because I factored a $z$ out of the summation.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that little $z$ in front of the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on what is trying to be achieved here.

Let $\gamma_r(t)=re^{it}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and
$$
F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_kz^k=\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}\tag{1}
$$
Define
$$
\omega_\pm=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\tag{2}
$$
Then $1-z-z^2=(w_\mp-z)(z-w_\pm)$.

The residue of $\dfrac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}=\dfrac1{z^n(1-z-z^2)}$ at $0$ (the coefficient of $1/z$) is $f_n$.

The residue of $\dfrac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}$ at $\omega_\pm$ is $\dfrac1{\omega_\pm^n(\omega_\mp-\omega_\pm)}$; i.e. multiply by $(z-\omega_\pm)$ and evaluate at $\omega_\pm$.

As $r\to\infty$, $|F(z)|\sim\frac1r$ on $\gamma_r$. Therefore, for $n\ge0$,
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_\gamma\frac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{3}
$$
Thus, by the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), the sum of the residues at $0$, $\omega_+$, and $\omega_-$ must be $0$, that is
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=f_n+\frac1{\omega_+^n(\omega_--\omega_+)}+\frac1{\omega_-^n(\omega_+-\omega_-)}\\
&=f_n-\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac{(-1/\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where we note that $\omega_+=1/\phi$ and $\omega_-=-\phi$ ($\phi$ is the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)). $(4)$ implies [Binet's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression):
$$
f_n=\frac{\phi^n-(-1/\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: could you elaborate on this part? The residue of $\dfrac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}$ at $\omega_\pm$ is $\dfrac1{\omega_\pm^n(\omega_\mp-\omega_\pm)}$; i.e. multiply by $(z-\omega_\pm)$ and evaluate at $\omega_\pm$.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: Other than at $z=0$, the poles are [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles). The residue of $f$ at a simple pole $z=c$ is $$\lim_{z\to c}(z-c)f(z)$$ If $(z-c)f(z)$ is continuous, simple evaluation at $c$ suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$F(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2} = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 5x^4 + 8x^5 + 13x^6 + 21x^7 + 34x^8 + \ldots$$

Put $\varphi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ and $\bar \varphi$ its conjugate, these are the two roots of $1-x-x^2$.

**(1)** Then $F(x)$ has a positive radius of convergence by [the ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) which gives $r = \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n/f_{n+1}| = \bar \varphi$.

**(2)**  $1 = (1-x-x^2)F(x) = F(x) - x F(x) - x^2 F(x)$ so the coefficients of this generating function satisfy the same recurrence as the fibonacci sequence. In fact $x^n$ is $f_n$ the $n$th fibonacci number.

**(3)** $\text{Res}(\frac{1}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)},z=0) = f_n$ by the [residue limit formula for higher poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles).

**(4)** By Theorem 9.9 which states $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{\rho} \text{Res}(f(z)),z=\rho)$$ summing over all residues we have $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)} = 2 \pi i [f_n + R_\varphi + R_{\bar \varphi}]$$ since there are three residues (one at 0, one at $\varphi$, one at $\bar \varphi$.)

For the integral let $\gamma(t) = R e^{it}$ so we have $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{i R e^{it} dt}{R^{n+1}e^{it(n+1)}(1-(Re^{it})-(Re^{it})^2)}$$ and as $R \to \infty$ this integral tends vanishes since the denominator becomes infinite: look at each factor, $R^{n+1}$ obviously blows up, $e^{it(n+1)}$ has absolute value 1 so it's ignorable, for $R > \varphi$ the last factor $(1-(Re^{it})-(Re^{it})^2)$ will always be bounded below by some constant, so we can ignore this too.

For the other two residues we can use the [residue formula for simple poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles): $$R_\varphi = \text{Res}(\frac{1}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)},z=\varphi) = \lim_{z \to \varphi}\frac{z-\varphi}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)} = \frac{1}{\varphi^{n+1}(1-\bar \varphi)}$$

Comment: My only question is where the z^n+1 appears from

Comment: For the history of this question/poster, please see my comment on the question.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, which z^n+1? also this answer is not complete, I couldn't finish the proof.. that's why I made it community wiki hope someone else will.

Comment: Also we haven't justified taking $R$ any larger than $\bar \varphi$ which we proceed to do in the integral... presumably the denominator term makes it ok?

Comment: @user58512 Yes, I can't try to edit it though because of my new user rep. Also, I'm referring to the z^n+1 that appears in the integral after you apply the residue theory.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, which one do you mean?

Comment: @user58512 "summing over all residues we have:" The z^n+1 in that following integral. Where do they get it from?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Instead of getting upset with my newness to the forum, could you possibly provide some input to the problem set at hand? It would be very appreciated indeed.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, why do you care about this complex analysis thing anyway? You can get Binet formula in a much more natural way.

Comment: @user58512 I'm just very interested in this way of derivation. So I'd like to see a complete solution on how to derive it using these methods

Comment: @user58512 Also, would you mind elaborating on (3) by showing the work involved?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, edited.. the link shows a formula which if you know about the maclaurin series.. you'll se this is ust the nth coefficient: so part 2 proves its the f_n.

Comment: @user58512 Alright, that makes more sense. I still don't understand why the z^n+1 suddenly appears.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, I just put it there because it says so in the problem sheet..

Comment: @user58512 Ahh, okay. But I'm trying to figure out why they did that. @ anyone Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: @user58512 At the very end, why did the numerator go from 1 to z-phi?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, take any generating function and divide it by z^n+1..  and now take the residue at 0: WHat happens? That's why.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, that's just a change of variables z = R e^it in the integral.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, why don't you say a bit about why you want this proof? what do you hope to gain from it? or do you just think it would be something nice to frame and put on a wall

Comment: @user58512 "For the other two residues we can use the residue formula for simple poles" I mean for that limit as z->phi why did you replace the 1 in the numerator with z - phi?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, oh that *is* just applying the formula linked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles - there are various different formula you can use to compute residues in different cases.

Comment: @user58512 Are you referring to this formula? http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/c/0/8c0610b5b2b6319181560b0a209a3c62.png Because then I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, yes why dont you answer my question.

Comment: @user58512 Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't see it. I just want to see the derivation for my own personal knowledge. Just a curiousity

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, you said that before too.. that doesn't answer though... I'm asking *why*.

Comment: @user58512 Because I'm slowly self-studying complex analysis and this was something that I came across and found interesting. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, yes. thank you. Im sorry I can't give a more correct answer.. at least I think this is roughly what a correct proof would look like and contains the ideas: I am bad at calculus and integrals so the details are somehow wrong.

Comment: @user58512 Of course, no problem. Could you elaborate on how the limit z -> phi gives the final equation of your work?

Comment: @user58512 No problem, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, it's just $(z-\varphi)/(1-z-z^2) = 1/(z-\bar \varphi)$ because $(1-z-z^2)=(\varphi-z)(\bar \varphi - z)$ and then plug in $\varphi$ now that there's no divide by zero left. You'd compute the other residue and get a similar thing then you'd have 0 = f_n + R_1 + R_2 --> f_n = binet formula after simplifying a little.

Comment: @user58512 Okay, that's what I was thinking. & what do you mean?

Comment: mean about what?

Comment: Please continue this discussion in chat.  There's a link below the comment box.

Comment: "You'd compute the other residue and get a similar thing then you'd have 0 = f_n + R_1 + R_2 --> f_n = binet formula after simplifying a little." Is R_2 harder to calculate then R_1? & why does 0 = f_n + R_1 + R_2?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I don't have a high enough rep

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, no the calculation is exactly the same. "why does 0 = f_n + R_1 + R_2?" ust look at the formula in part 4: the LHS is the integral we proved to be zero and the RHS is just that.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: What makes you think it's acceptable to deface someone else's answer?

Comment: the fact you tried to delete the entire content of this post... which was the first post that gave a complete outline of how to solve the problem (combined with the evasiveness when I asked you to say why you were interested in this) suggests something.....

Answer (score 0):

The theorem gives us $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z^{n+1}(1-z-z^2)} = 2 \pi i [f_n + R\varphi + R_{\bar \varphi}]$$

and we prove that the integral tends to 0 as R tends to infinity, so that gives us

$$0 = 2 \pi i [f_n + R\varphi + R_{\bar \varphi}]$$

(as the RHS didn't depend on R) thus

$$f_n = -R\varphi - R_{\bar \varphi}$$

and these Residue terms should simplify into Binets formula once they are calculated correctly.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what I put in the edit?